# php orm framework

Tags: php, orm

I have a small school management project. There are a few thousand records per table (invoices, persons, classes...) to be managed. Classic webapplication with HTML/AJAX UI and MySQL/PHP backend.

To save some time and have a better code I want to use a ORM for MySQL, which will handle most of the database transaction for me.

What is the best ORM to use in this case?

thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) is an extremely powerful ORM library.

Comment: There are plenty out there, but Doctrine seems to be the most widely used. It is also used by the Symfony project which is one of the more popular PHP web frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at a framework WITH an orm rather than just an orm. There will be a lot of legwork to get an ORM working with a database that the frameworks do for you. The easiest to get off the ground in a working state are probably CakePHP, CodeIgniter, and Symphony. AFAIK all of these have very handy code generation tools that will create a scaffold application in no time.

Answer (score 0):

As simshaun suggested, check out Doctrine, or alternatively [Propel](http://www.propelorm.org/)

Answer (score 0):

I really like using [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/) with [DataMapper](http://stensi.com/datamapper/).

CodeIgniter is a PHP framwork that is extremely easy to get used to even if you like pure PHP.

DataMapper is a great ORM based on the library from the famous Ruby On Rails framework.

Answer (score 0):

Kohana's ORM library is drop-dead simple to use and configure which makes it great for most small-medium projects. Doctrine and Propel are great but require more decision making to be made upfront because they use code generation (probably not the best choice for a school project). They're both more flexible (ton of config options) than kohana's or code igniter's ORM, but they have a steeper learning curve and involve much more configuration (read about 'convention vs configuration').

An example of Kohana 3's ORM:

```
// Model definition file - /classes/model/animal.php

class Model_Animal extends ORM
{
    /* Find all animals that bark */
    public function barking_animals()
    {
        return $this->where('sound', '=', 'barker')->find_all();
    }

    /* Find all animals that quack */
    public function quacking_animals
    {
        return $this->where('sound', '=', 'quack')->find_all();
    }
}

// In some controller file somewhere...

$loudAnimals = ORM::factory('animal')->barking_animals();

// don't rent an apartment if you're neighbors have any of these animals...
foreach ($loudAnimals as $animal)
{
    echo $animal->name;
}

// add a new animal to db
$newAnimal = orm::factory('animal');
$newAnimal->name = 'Obese Cat';
$newAnimal->weight = '30lbs';
$newAnimal->sound = 'fat quack';
$newAnimal->save();
```

Finally, some reference material... http://kohanaframework.org/guide/tutorials.orm